# Credit Score down after being approved by a credit card

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

First time asking a questions here, apologies for any mistakes in advance.

I applied for my first ever credit card online and I was approved for it within seconds. But when I checked my credit score I saw that my score had gone down by 16 points.

Is this usual after being approved for credit card. Will the score go up?

These might be very basic questions but it's my first time and don't want to mess up my score.

Comment: applying for a credit card causes something known as a "hard pull" on your credit report that gets logged in the credit report and causes the score to fall somewhat as well as your increased credit account levels. See other answers for an explanation of why. and how it works

Comment: @MD-Tech thank you I'll go through the question you linked. But do you think its something I should be hugely worried about? In your opinion is this normal.

Comment: it is normal and expected. They have to do it to make sure that you qualify for the credit

Answer (score 3):

When you apply for a credit card, the credit card company issues a hard pull on your credit which will lower your credit score by a few points. You will usually make this up in a few months if you pay your credit card on time.

Comment: I think that this will also lower the average age of OP's credit lines

Comment: @DanielCarson Yes. You are correct.